# WPF DataGrid selected row style

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I'm stuck with one very stupid problem - need to style selected row in WPF DataGrid.

I want to show a rectangle with blue border instead of just filling entire row with some color.

Any ideas how to implement this? It just must be some way to make it pretty easy.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use `CellStyle` and `RowStyle` on `DataGrid`. `DataGridCell` and `DataGridRow` both have `IsSelected` property that can be used in a `Trigger` to find out if they are selected.

Something like following should do the trick:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Just play around until you get it right.

Comment: Border is rendering just how I wanted, but I can't do anything with background/foreground colors, when selecting a row It is filling with a solid blue

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to say that `Background` and `Foreground` colors don't apply? Can you post the code that you used? Which version of WPF are you using?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem Illegal-Immigrant had; it doesn't seem possible to override the default blue row background colour, only the border colour.

Comment: I set the column widths using \*, 2\* etc. , so that the columns exactly fill the width of the grid. If I set BorderThickness=2 in the RowStyle, this causes the datagrid to have a horizontal scrollbar. As a an alternative, I have set the BorderThickness to "0,1,0,1", so that it only displays a border above and below the row.

Answer (score 10):

I like this one:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Margin="4" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>

                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <DataGridRowHeader SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4,1,4,4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3886B9"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>-->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried this solution. It works. but then it introduced another problem. I have one hyper linked Cell in a row. If I apply this setter on IsSelected = true. then I need to click on hyper link twice. is there any way to avoid this?