# Making a row non-focusable in a WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to figure out how to make the rows in the following WPF DataGrid non-focusable. As you can see I tried adding a `<DataGrid.Resources>` section to the DataGrid where I'm specifying a DataGrid cell style but this isn't working. What am I missing?

```
<DataGrid Name="grdResources"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
CanUserReorderColumns="False" ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader">

<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="Select" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Select_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Key" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Key}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**EDIT**
For those interested I ended up overriding the SelectedRow style so it doesn't highlight the row when selected. Here is my `<DataGrid.Resources>` section after that change:

```
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `IsHitTestVisible = False`

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoFocusColumStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Then apply the style to whatever columns you want to restrict focus for

```
<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource NoFocusColumStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for making the row non-focusable, however, I have a checkbox column as the first column in the DataGrid for row selection and this makes the checkbox un-clickable.

Comment: @Tom Add a Key to your Style, and in your `DataGrid.Columns` apply the Cell Style to the columns that should be ReadOnly. `<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource NoFocusColumn}" ... />`

Comment: This still leaves the checkbox column as selectable though. I want to be able to click the checkbox to select the row without any cells being selected and subsequently highlighted. Sorry if I didn't specify this clearly in my OP

Comment: @Tom It sounds like what you really want is to override the SelectedRow style so it doesn't highlight the row. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/4539909/302677 for an example at how to do that

Comment: That post was what I needed. Thanks!