# How to make all the columns non-focusable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

To make a column non-focusable, one can set the style of its cells as shown [in some answers on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778469/1525840). However, if one wishes to set **all** the cells of **all** the columns, that starts to look like a needless code repetition, since the cell style needs to be added to each column definition.

Is there a way to sett the cell style for all the cells (all the columns' cells, perhaps, or all of the data grid) at once?

I've tried to do the following but it created a parsing error during the compile, guessingly because the style I'm referring to isn't defined at the point of accessing it, yet.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource NoFocusOncell}"
          ItemsSource="{...}">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoFocusOnCell"
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
      <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
    </Style>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  ...
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implicit styling (take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements.aspx)).
You have just to remove the key from the style and the CellStyle property in this way:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In this way you can declare your style just one time. I hope it can help you.

Comment: That did it. +1 for clean answer, code sample **and** a link to a blog for extra information. This answer is a school book example of what an answer should look like! On the other hand, I'm starting to believe that I don't really understand the concept of why *x:Key* is there and what it does...

Comment: Thank you @KonradViltersten for your compliments ;-)