# change style of a single cell in a datagrid WPF / C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

code below sets a background color in a cell of datagrid, however when scrolling the grid. to scroll the grid values ​​are changing.

anyone know a solution?

```
foreach (var item in dgrid.SelectedItems)
            {
                var row = this.dgDados.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dgDados) as DataGridRow;

                if (row == null)
                {
                    dgDados.UpdateLayout();
                    dgDados.ScrollIntoView(dgDados.Items.IndexOf(item));
                    row = (DataGridRow)dgDados.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dgDados.Items.IndexOf(item));
                }
                row.Background = corLinha;
            }
```

Comment: Probably by using MVVM and in the **cell template** binding the `Background` to the values. Please share more information...

Answer (score 1):

in WPF you shouldn't do something like this in code - Use a `Trigger` in  your `XAML`...

have a look at [WPF DataGrid selected row style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539909)

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyHeader" Binding="{Binding Path=MyPath, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle> 
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution, but it's good to try to explain what exactly you're doing to help the asker. They usually are asking because they lack information, not just a solution. So a thorough (even if brief) description of your solution is helpfull