# WPF GridView: Determining held item

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to highlight the selected item in a bridview from a windows application.

To be more precise:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46" 
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="openRessource"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="250"  Holding="openHoldMenu">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding icon}" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Image Source="{Binding downloaded}" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

This is my XAML, fairly simple, I just have a Holding event which brings up a menu in my page.

My problem is that I want to know which item has been held to create a border around it so that the user knows which item is selected.

I can easily access the bound item in my list but can't get the grid element selected.

If anyone know how to, that would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to make a trigger such as this: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539909/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-style](http://WPF%20DataGrid%20Selected%20Row%20Style)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
Unfortunately, in windows application Style triggers are not available.